# How to use custom class to show different images for different devices in TailwindCSS?

Tags: tailwind-css

In Laravel 8 / tailwindcss 2 app I wand to show different image as background in class:

```
  <i class="test-device px-5"></i>
```

With custom class defined :

```
.test-device {
    background: url(lg:/img/test-device/lg.png xl:/img/test-device/exlg.png md:/img/test-device/md.png ;
```

but that does not work and background image is not displayed anyway.

Which way is valid?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can extend the [`backgroundImage` utility](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/background-image#background-images) to add the custom backgrounds in your `tailwind.config.js`.

```js
// tailwind.config.js

module.exports = {
    theme: {
        extend: {
            backgroundImage: theme => ({
                'test-device-md': "url('/img/test-device/md.png')",
                'test-device-lg': "url('/img/test-device/lg.png')",
                'test-device-xl': "url('/img/test-device/exlg.png')",
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Then, use the generated `bg-*` classes at the appropriate breakpoints.

```html
<i class="px-5 md:bg-test-device-md lg:bg-test-device-lg xl:bg-test-device-xl"></i>
```

Comment: Thanks! It works! Could you please to explain  how bg-test-device-md works as background Image for defined test-device-md themes? Some rules in naming ?

Comment: The images you add under `backgroundImage` will be available as `bg-` prefixed classes. Have a read through the [background image docs](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/background-image#background-images) directly.